# Cannot find field name in Object Manager

Tags: fields

I have an object that's called `Contact` with a field name `LastName` (i know because when i create a new object through the REST API i set this field, which is required).

Yet, when i go to Setup -> Object Manager -> Fields & Relationship, i can't find it in that list.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of a Compound Field called Name. If you click on the Name field, you'll see the components of that field: Salutation, FirstName, MiddleName (if enabled), LastName, Suffix. Note that (apparently) this does not appear in the Lightning Experience, but you can see them in Classic Setup. They also appear in the Documentation and the WSDL.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't appear in Lightning but it does in Classic. Thanks!